# C# performance of multiple &&s using local variable with complex checks - coding style vs performance

Tags: c#, performance, architecture, logical-operators

I'm having the following code:

```
    using System;
public static class C {
    public static bool WhatIsFaster(object someObject) {
       var isHttpRequest = IsHttpRequest(someObject);
       var userIsKnown = RequestorIsInDatabase(someObject);
       var parameterIsInChecklist = RequestParametersIsInCheckList(someObject);
       var permissionGranted = AskPersmissionServerice(someObject);
       return isHttpRequest && userIsKnown && parameterIsInChecklist && permissionGranted;

        //return GetValue1() && GetValue2() && GetValue3();
    }

    public static bool IsHttpRequest(object someObject){
        //Check the kind of request
        return true;
    }

    public static bool RequestorIsInDatabase(object someObject){
        //Check if the user from the reqeust is known
        return true;
    }

    public static bool RequestParametersIsInCheckList(object someObject){
        //Check if the parameters is in the check list
        return true;
    }

    public static bool AskPersmissionServerice(object someObject){
        //Check if the user has permission for this
        return true;
    }

}
```

The out-commented way is much faster, because the execution of the methods is only done when the previous execution returned true. Using the extra local variables makes the code much more readable.

Taking this easy sample to a more complex with more parameters and evaluation methods, I'm not sure how to implement this. The implementation I'm looking for, needs to be really performant, because the amount of requests for this code is really high and some for the Evaluation-Methods (GetValueX-Methods) might need longer as others.

I was thinking if nested 'ifs' might be better, but it would raise complexity and maintainability. Especially, if I consider that the final evaluation might get complexer by more Evaluation-Methods and different logical inclusions (XORs, ORs).

Which ways or other approaches do you see to optimize this and still have a good readable and maintainable code?

Comment: This is a bit broad and opinion-based, but here's another alternative anyway that doesn't use nested if statements - `if (!GetValue1()) return false; if (!GetValue2()) return false;` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measure the method which takes most time, after that structure the code like @stuartd mention

```
if(!LessTimeToExecuteMethod())
   return false;

if(!NextWithLessTimeToExecuteMethod())
   return false;

...

//last one
if(!TheMostTimeToExecute())
   return false;

return true;
```

The effect which you had seen in your comment code is happening because statements like

```
bool result = a && b && c ;//and so on ...
```

are calculated to the first occurrence of false.

When you calculate every a, b, c separately you will have worst performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can *chain* result using extension methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool And(this bool @this, Func<bool> func) => @this && func();
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    True().And(True).And(True).And(False).And(True);
}

static bool True() => true;
static bool False() => false;
```

First method you execute as normal and then call others via extension method. In example above last true will not be called.

It should be possible to add parameters as an extension method parameters, I'll leave this to you ;) Or just call methods via lambdas (a bit slower).

Comment: Cool. Tanks for that advice. I needed a little to understand this completely. Really nice way to implement it. Now readable and good structurable methods like the following ar possible:  var test = LessTimeToExecuteMethod()
                .And(NextWithLessTimeToExecuteMethod)
                .And(NextWithLessTimeToExecuteMethod2);